# is thermostatTemperatureAmbient required?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I'm trying to implement action.devices.types.AC_UNIT in google home.
My hub is the IR transmitter, it saves previous states and commands with a packet.
As you might understand the device does not know anything about room temperature.

It seems like thermostatTemperatureAmbient is required for setTemperature execution.
I can report the desired temperature as the ambient one, but then google reports this value when I ask for the temperature at home.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `thermostatTemperatureSetpoint` for your desired temperature setting. Ambient temperature should be the actual temp reading from the device. However, since your device does not actually read the temperature, you may consider using the [TemperatureControl](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/temperaturecontrol) trait instead.